# Column spacing Bootstrap 4

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently developing an TYPO3 Extension for a website.
I am using bootstrap 4 and i have three different parts for the extension.
On web it should look like:

A B
C

and on mobile:

A
B
C

Mobile view is fine with my current approach:
[mobile view](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1AFEh.png)

A is just a selection picker, B is a Google Map and C are Results.
The columns have different heights.

[Currenlty looking like on web](https://i.stack.imgur.com/N1IOG.png)

My issue: I don't want Column C to have this much margin. In fact I want it to be just underneath column A.

My code:

```
        <!DOCTYPE html>
        <f:layout name="Default" />
        <f:section name="main">
        <div class="row kleingaerten container">
                <select class="selectpicker col-12 col-sm-4" data-header="Wähle einen Bezirk"  data-live-search="true">
                    <option data-tokens="">Alle Bezirke</option>
                        <f:for each="{bezirke}" as="bezirk">
                            <option data-tokens="b{bezirk.uid}" >{bezirk.name}</option>
                        </f:for>
                </select>


            <div class="col-12 col-sm-8">
                <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:400px;" ></div>
            </div>


            <div class="col-12 col-sm-4">
                <f:for each="{kleingaerten}" as="kleingarten">
                    <div class="card  {kleingarten.bezirkClasses} " data-lat="{kleingarten.adresse.breitengrad}" data-lng="{kleingarten.adresse.laengengrad}" data-name="{kleingarten.titel}" data-strasse="{kleingarten.adresse.strasse}" data-hausnummer="{kleingarten.adresse.hausnummer}" data-plz="{kleingarten.adresse.postleitzahl}" data-ort="{kleingarten.adresse.stadt}" data-webauftritt='<a href="#">Kleingarten</a>'
                    id="g{kleingarten.uid}" data-id="g{kleingarten.uid}"
                    >
                        <div class="container">
                            <h7><b>{kleingarten.titel}</b></h7> 
                            <div>{kleingarten.adresse.strasse} {kleingarten.adresse.hausnummer}</div> 
                            <div>{kleingarten.adresse.postleitzahl}
                            {kleingarten.adresse.stadt}</div> 
                            <a href="#">Kleingarten</a>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </f:for>
            </div>
    </div>
</f:section> 
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

```html
<link href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet"/>

<div class="row">
  <div class="col-12 col-md-4">
    <div>
      Part A
    </div>
    <div>
      Part B <br>
      Part B <br>
      Part B <br>
      Part B <br>
      Part B <br>
      Part B <br>
      Part B <br>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-12 col-md-8">
  Part C (Map part in your app)
  </div>
</div>
```

> You don't need to separate as 3 parts.
>
> You can insert A and B into one div like code snippet.

And You need to change

**FROM**

```
"col-12 col-sm-8"
"col-12 col-sm-4"
```

**TO**

```
"col-8 col-sm-12"
"col-4 col-sm-12"
```

Comment: Thank you, but this would put my Map at the bottom in the mobile view, wouldn't it? On mobile I need my Map to be shown in the middle on mobile.

Comment: "col-8 col-sm-12" this means this column's width is 8/12 of parent, but if browser is small (sm) then width will be 12/12 (full width of parent)

Comment: Please run my code snippet, then you will see A and B and C will locate vertically. click full page on running code snippet in my answer, then you will see the part C will be the right side as you want.

Comment: But it's not the order I want to achieve on mobile. On desktop it's fine. But as C is now my map, i need A C B as my order for the mobile view, not A B C. Your solution was also my first approach in the beginning

Comment: in your question, you wrote A, B, C order in your question.

Comment: Yeah, but in my question B was the map, not C. Thank you anyway

Answer (score 1):

Just follow this steps and fiddle or snippet below.(resize screen to check)

Step 1:Make B column first and use bootstrap class .float-md-right

Step 2:Make A column second and add class .order-first(for moving to top 
       in mobile view)

Step 3:Make C column last.

Wrap 3 columns A,B,C in div and add class .d-flex to make .order class to work and .flex-wrap class to wrap when screen size changes and .d-md-block to override .d-flex and make it work only on mobile devices

https://jsfiddle.net/raj_mutant/9vgL605f/

```css
#map {
  background: green;
}

.a-section {
  background: yellow;
  height: 100px;
}

.c-section {
  background: red;
  height: 400px;
}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div class="container my-4">
  <div class="d-flex d-md-block flex-wrap">
    <div class="col-md-8 col-12  float-md-right">
      <div id="map" style="width:100%; height:400px;">B</div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4 order-first">
      <div class="a-section">
        A
      </div>
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-4">
      <div class="c-section">
        C
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: This will not solve the question. please B has some height, then C will have many gap with A. Please see the image attached on question.

Comment: Thanks. That was also my first approach. But this does only work when C is my map. But my map is B. On mobile view I want to map to be presented in between my selection picker and my results. On web view the map should be presented at the right side as my screenshot shows. Sorry if it's unclear what I'am trying to achieve

Comment: hi just check the fiddle its updated now.Now in web view A and C is one below other(with different height)and B is parallel.In Mobile view it displays as A B C. https://jsfiddle.net/raj_mutant/9vgL605f/

Comment: hi @Toranksu .Is this above new solution worked for you?